# Parsing: a sentence from Russell's The History of Western Philosophy

Tags: sentence-construction

> The Persian satrap at Sardes represented that he intended to rebel
>   against the Great King, and would pay vast sums for the help of
>   Polycrates, who went to the mainland for an interview, was captured
>   and crucified.

My parsing:

*The Persian satrap* is **S**ubject.

**S**ubject represented that (**Clause A**).

**Clause A**:

**S** intended to do sth, and (**S**) would do sth for the help of Polycrates, (**Relative clause B**), was captured and crucified.

My question: is "was captured and crucified" part of **Relative clause B**?

Comment: @Sander I edited the description.

Answer (score 1):

It's Polycrates.  Not only because he is the most recently mentioned, but because the "who" right after Polycrates' name tells that it is he who "went..[and] was captured and crucified."

...Polycrates, **who** ....

Comment: Do you mean that the conjunction "and" is simply omited?

Comment: Yes, basically. It's clear the same person "went" who was "captured and [was] crucified. See, there's an implied "was" as well—otherwise it might mean that he, rather than having been crucified, crucified some other unnamed person!

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm still confused. Is "was captured and crucified" part of the relative clause "who went to the mainland for an interview, (and was captured and crucified)"? It seems wierd.

Comment: Sorry. I understand now. I am such a fool!!!